# Something incorrect in shell path/syntax

Tags: shell, lua, sh, mediawiki-extensions

I'm trying to instal Extension:Scribuntu, but when I try to run simple command, like #invoke I get the error:

> Lua error: Internal error: The interpreter exited with status 127.

This is what I found in error logfile:

```
sh: /var/lib/php-exec//sh /alt/home/webmaster.plast/html/Wiki/extensions/Scribunto/engines/LuaStandalone/lua_ulimit.sh 7 8 51200 \\/alt/home/webmaster.plast/html/Wiki/extensions/Scribunto/engines/LuaStandalone/binaries/lua5_1_5_linux_64_generic/lua\: No such file or directory
```

So my question is: can You tell me if the paths are correct? I've checked the files and they are all in place. Paths also are absolute so I have no idea where the problem is. Are those "\" before path correct? 
I have never used shell before so i don't even know the correct syntax. Thank You for simple explanation.

Comment: not sure about the last /

Answer (score 1):

There should be no "\" in the path, but it's possible that this is an artifact of the error reporting/logging machanism. Do check though.

Another thing to check is that the user executing the code actually has the permissions needed to read and run the lua executable (and the directory where it resides, and all parent directories). For apache under Debian or Ubuntu, that user would typically be www-data. It should be fine to make the lua executable readable and runnable for all users.